# En una fila creada por Jquery, ¿como nombrar inputs que se van creando?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día. Tengo la siguiente situación, tengo una tabla, que va generando filas cada vez que se presiona el botón 'agregar', dentro de los TDs creados hay unos **input** que guardan la información almacenada, todo lo anterior esta dentro de un **form** que va a un archivo que inserta a la base de datos, pero como puedo nombrar a los **input** de forma dinámica por `jquery`?

**Mi código es este:**

```js
function addProduct(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const row = createRow({
    codP: $('#codP').val(),
    qty: $('#qty').val(),
 nomP: $('#nomP').val(),
 typeP: $('#typeP').val(),
 presentationP: $('#presentationP').val(),
 priceP: $('#priceP').val(),
 total: $('#total').val()
  });
  $('#tabla tbody').append(row);
  clean();
}

function createRow(data) {
  return (
    `<tr align='center' id='fila'>` +
      `<td><input type='text' name='resulta' value='${data.codP}' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
      `<td><input type='text' name='resultb' value='${data.qty}' size='1' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resultc' value='${data.nomP}' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resultd' value='${data.typeP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resulte' value='${data.presentationP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><b>¢</b><input type='text' name='resultf' value='${data.priceP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><b>¢</b><input type='text' name='resultg' value='${data.total}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input id='borrarFila' type='button' value='Eliminar' title='Eliminar Línea'></td>` +
    `</tr>`
  );
}


function clean() {
  $('#codP').val('');
  $('#qty').val('');
  $('#nomP').val('');
  $('#typeP').val('');
  $('#presentationP').val('');
  $('#priceP').val('');
  $('#total').val('');
  $('#codP').focus();
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" border="1" id="tabla">
     <tr align="left">
         <td colspan="7">
            <h2 align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;IV. Orden de Pedido</h2>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
            Usuario que registra: <input type="text" size="7" name="creador" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['idu'] ?>" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr align="center">
         <td valign="top">Código/UPC</td>
            <td valign="top">Cantidad</td>
            <td valign="top">Producto</td>
            <td valign="top">Tipo de Pan</td>
            <td valign="top">Presentación</td>
            <td valign="top">Precio</td>
            <td valign="top">Total</td>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2">Administrar</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="ui-widget">
        <tr align="center" id="esta"><div class="ui-widget">
         <td valign="top"><input type="text" id="codP" class="codP" name="ean" placeholder="Código del Producto" maxlength="13" autocomplete="off" title="Ingrese el Código del Producto" />
            
            </td>
               <td valign="top">
      <select name="qty" id="qty" title="Seleccione la Cantidad" onChange="multiplicar();">
             <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
               </select> 
                        </td>
            <td valign="top">
                 
       <input type="text" id="nomP" name="PName" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="typeP" id="typeP" size="10" title="Tipo de Producto"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="presentationP" id="presentationP" size="10" title="Presentación del Producto"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><b>¢</b><input type="text" name="priceP" id="priceP" size="10" title="Precio Unitario"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><b>¢</b><input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" title="Total de Fila"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><input id="agregarFila" type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="addProduct(event)" title="Agregar Producto"/></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Entonces concertadamente, necesito colocar el valor **name** a estos **input** que se van generando con este código

```
function createRow(data) {
  return (
    `<tr align='center' id='fila'>` +
    `<td><input type='text' name='resulta' value='${data.codP}' 
      disabled='disabled'></td>` +
```

Como ven el **name** que le coloqué 'resulta' necesitaría que vaya generándose como **'resulta1'**, **'resulta2'**, **'resulta3'**, etc.

Gracias por ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para tener los name dinamicos puedes agregarle esto `name='resulta${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}` que te va a retornar un numero unico para cada tr e hijos input espero te ayude saludos.

> NOTA: Se obtinene el total de tr en la tabla con `$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length` y ese numero es el asignado al name lo que quiere decir que es único para cada input dentro de el.

```js
function addProduct(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const row = createRow({
    codP: $('#codP').val(),
    qty: $('#qty').val(),
 nomP: $('#nomP').val(),
 typeP: $('#typeP').val(),
 presentationP: $('#presentationP').val(),
 priceP: $('#priceP').val(),
 total: $('#total').val()
  });
  $('#tabla tbody').append(row);
  clean();
}

function createRow(data) {
  return (
    `<tr align='center' id='fila'>` +
      `<td><input type='text' name='resulta${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.codP}' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
      `<td><input type='text' name='resultb${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.qty}' size='1' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resultc${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.nomP}' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resultd${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.typeP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input type='text' name='resulte${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.presentationP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><b>¢</b><input type='text' name='resultf' value='${data.priceP}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><b>¢</b><input type='text' name='resultg${$('#tabla tbody').find("tr").length}' value='${data.total}' size='10' disabled='disabled'></td>` +
   `<td><input id='borrarFila' type='button' value='Eliminar' title='Eliminar Línea'></td>` +
    `</tr>`
  );
}


function clean() {
  $('#codP').val('');
  $('#qty').val('');
  $('#nomP').val('');
  $('#typeP').val('');
  $('#presentationP').val('');
  $('#priceP').val('');
  $('#total').val('');
  $('#codP').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" border="1" id="tabla">
     <tr align="left">
         <td colspan="7">
            <h2 align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;IV. Orden de Pedido</h2>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
            Usuario que registra: <input type="text" size="7" name="creador" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['idu'] ?>" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
        </tr>
     <tr align="center">
         <td valign="top">Código/UPC</td>
            <td valign="top">Cantidad</td>
            <td valign="top">Producto</td>
            <td valign="top">Tipo de Pan</td>
            <td valign="top">Presentación</td>
            <td valign="top">Precio</td>
            <td valign="top">Total</td>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2">Administrar</td>
        </tr>
        <div class="ui-widget">
        <tr align="center" id="esta"><div class="ui-widget">
         <td valign="top"><input type="text" id="codP" class="codP" name="ean" placeholder="Código del Producto" maxlength="13" autocomplete="off" title="Ingrese el Código del Producto" />
            
            </td>
               <td valign="top">
      <select name="qty" id="qty" title="Seleccione la Cantidad" onChange="multiplicar();">
             <option value="">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
               </select> 
                        </td>
            <td valign="top">
                 
       <input type="text" id="nomP" name="PName" placeholder="Nombre del Producto" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="typeP" id="typeP" size="10" title="Tipo de Producto"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><input type="text" name="presentationP" id="presentationP" size="10" title="Presentación del Producto"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><b>¢</b><input type="text" name="priceP" id="priceP" size="10" title="Precio Unitario"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><b>¢</b><input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" title="Total de Fila"  disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td valign="top"><input id="agregarFila" type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="addProduct(event)" title="Agregar Producto"/></td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu respuesta! Fijate que me queda como campo 'undefined' en todos los inputs a la hora de crear el nuevo TR...